# Pandas adding column with date

Tags: python, pandas, datediff

I want to add an date difference column where it would take some date and subtract to the date column in the df.  The tricky part is that it would only calculate if there's a string X in the Name column if the Id does not show up twice.  For example,

df

```
Id Date Name

111 1/1/17 Xyz

123 1/2/17 Xab

222 1/1/17 abc

222 1/2/17 Xab

333 1/1/17 abc 

333 1/2/17 def
```

If I use currentdate = datetime.date(2017,5, 1), the result would be:

```
Id Date Name Diff

111 1/1/17 Xyz 4  

123 1/2/17 Xab 3  

222 1/1/17 abc 0  

222 1/2/17 Xab 0  (this is 0 since 222 already showed up)

333 1/1/17 abc 0

333 1/2/17 def 0
```

My approach was to group them by the string 'X' but I'm not sure how to take in the unique row.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain how `1/1/17` - `5/31/17` is 4?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I meant 5/1/17-1/1/17 = 4

Comment: Which is first in your date? The day or the month?

Comment: The  first is the month mm/dd/yyyy :)

Comment: Wrote an answer, let me know if I misunderstood you somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a timestamp object -

```
d = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-5')
```

**Option 1**
Now, calculate the difference, and use `mask` to hide rows based on your condition -

```
m = df['Id'].duplicated(keep=False) | ~df['Name'].str.contains('X')
df['Diff'] = (d - pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).dt.days.mask(m, 0)

df

    Id    Date Name  Diff
0  111  1/1/17  Xyz     4
1  123  1/2/17  Xab     3
2  222  1/1/17  abc     0
3  222  1/2/17  Xab     0
4  333  1/1/17  abc     0
5  333  1/2/17  def     0
```

I use `pd.Series.duplicated` to remove those duplicate entries, and `str.contains` to check whether `X` is in `Name`.

---

**Option 2**
You could use `np.where`, but the approach is similar -

```
m = df['Id'].duplicated(keep=False) | ~df['Name'].str.contains('X')
df['Diff'] = np.where(m, 0, (d - pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).dt.days)

df

    Id    Date Name  Diff
0  111  1/1/17  Xyz     4
1  123  1/2/17  Xab     3
2  222  1/1/17  abc     0
3  222  1/2/17  Xab     0
4  333  1/1/17  abc     0
5  333  1/2/17  def     0
```

Comment: There's an error syntax when my Id field has a space in between, something like "Id num". Is there a way we can work around this?

Comment: @TylerNG Yes... use the `['...']` notation instead of the `.` notation. See my edit?

Comment: @COLDSPEED It's odd when I tried it on my end , the calculation is off whenever the date is not 1/1/17.   Maybe because my actual data is a lot more complex.  Would there be an approach where we look for the str X instead?  Just a thought.

Comment: @TylerNG Nah, I don't see how that would make sense, because `X` has nothing to do with duplicated Ids (I presume). Can you please change your data and provide a [mcve] that accurately reproduces the issue you get?

Comment: Let me post a new similar question and point out the error :)

Comment: Sure, go ahead and do that.

Comment: @TylerNG I am sure, this is the best approach~

Comment: Thanks Wen! But, it seems OP is having trouble adapting this to their actual data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ then , he need provide a reproduce sample data  :-)

Comment: I think I figured out where the problem is.   If I have a row like this:
Id    Date Name 
555 1/1/17 abc 
Your code would give diff = 4 since there's no dup in there but diff should still be 0 since X is not there.  
Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @TylerNG Okay, I've edited my answer, it should be exactly what you're looking for (if it is, don't forget to vote on, and accept. Cheers).